# NEST and TPL Data flow

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, tpl-dataflow

### Problem

We wrote a logging framework a while back that uses **NEST** to index logs to **ElasticSearch**. Currently I am upgrading the framework to do **bulk inserts** using the `BulkAsync(...)` call that NEST provides. We thought it would be handy to use **TPL data flow** to build up a batch request (using `BatchBlock` and `ActionBlock`) and then when the batch target is hit, ship it to the bulk indexing method. Problem is that when executing `BulkAsync`, or any other indexing method for that matter, inside the `ActionBlock` an exception is thrown (With message `"Thread was being aborted."`). This message and the stack trace was the only info I could get on the exception because visual studio couldn't show me the exception in xUnit's debug mode, basically I get (`"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack"`) **but that's unrelated**.

### Stack Trace

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Object o)\r\n   
at System.RuntimeType.GetHashCode()\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)\r\n   
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.GetTypeCode(Type t, Boolean& isEnum)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.GetTypeCode(Type t)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.IsJsonPrimitiveType(Type t)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)\r\n   
at Nest.Resolvers.ElasticContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\Resolvers\\ElasticContractResolver.cs:line 30\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)\r\n   
at Nest.Resolvers.SettingsContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\Resolvers\\SettingsContractResolver.cs:line 34\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetContractSafe(Object value)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Type type, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, Formatting formatting, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   
at Nest.NestSerializer.Serialize(Object data, SerializationFormatting formatting) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\ExposedInternals\\NestSerializer.cs:line 30\r\n   
at Nest.NestSerializer.SerializeBulkDescriptor(IBulkRequest bulkRequest) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\ExposedInternals\\NestSerializer.cs:line 175\r\n   
at Nest.ElasticClient.<BulkAsync>b__345_0(ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 p, IBulkRequest d) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\ElasticClient-Bulk.cs:line 44\r\n   
at Nest.ElasticClient.Nest.IHighLevelToLowLevelDispatcher.DispatchAsync[D,Q,R,I](D descriptor, Func`3 dispatch) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\ElasticClient.cs:line 88\r\n   
at Nest.ElasticClient.BulkAsync(IBulkRequest bulkRequest) in c:\\code\\elasticsearch-net\\src\\Nest\\ElasticClient-Bulk.cs:line 40\r\n   
at ElasticSearchLogger.<IndexLogEntriesAsync>d__f.MoveNext() in d:\\MyProject\\ElasticSearchLogger.cs:line 218
```

### What I've tried

I have tested the bulk indexing code outside of the `ActionBlock` and it works, it's just failing inside of the block. **Any ideas as to why this would happen?**

### Working Code

*Without using an ActionBlock to call it*

```
private async Task IndexLogEntriesAsync(IEnumerable<LogEntry> logEntries)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new BulkDescriptor();
        foreach (LogEntry logEntry in logEntries)
            request.Index<LogEntry>(op => op
                    .Index(_index)
                    .Type("logentry")
                    .Id(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                    .Document(logEntry));

        var result = await _elasticClient.BulkAsync(request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string m = e.Message; // Thread was being aborted.
        // No can do this logging thing.
    }
}
```

### What's breaking it

```
BatchBlock<LogEntry> batchBlock = new BatchBlock<LogEntry>(_batchSize); //batch size = 10
ActionBlock<IEnumerable<LogEntry>> asyncIndexer = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<LogEntry>>(
    async (le) =>
    {
        await this.IndexLogEntriesAsync(le);
    });

batchBlock.LinkTo(asyncIndexer, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

//And in the IndexLogEntry method call
batchBlock.Post(logEntry); //which builds up the batch and ships when the batch is full
```

### Update

I got rid of the TPL Data flow blocks and wrote my own solution, to test a different scenario. Used a `ConcurrentQueue` that constantly queues items and dequeues (from within a thread) either on a timeout or when the batch size was hit. I got exactly the same error.

Comment: is `ElasticClient` thread-safe? Can it handle concurrent calls to its async methods?

Comment: According to what I've read yes, see this link https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-1-3

Comment: Are you running this in Release mode? If so, switch to Debug. What is the actual error message thrown? Does the exception contain any inner exceptions perhaps?

Comment: I am running in debug mode, the actual exception message is "Thread was being aborted." as far as I can see (due to visual studio's lack of showing the exception) and there are no inner exceptions. The stack trace is basically as far as I can go in terms of interrogating the exception thrown.

Comment: Threads are aborted either because some code explicitly called Thread.Abort or a timeout occurred. Is this a web application? Did the request time out because the bulk operation takes too long?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are using a console application and forget to await the completion of the last block in the pipeline. The application will terminate once `Main` exits and any background threads will be aborted

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos, the important part here is going to be the code that calls this, probably all the way up to the top-level method (e.g. `Main`).

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos I am using xUnit's runner to execute this code. When I debug the first call to BulkAsync throws this exception immediately. Was definitely not due to a timeout (batch of 5 items) and the runner is also not killing the thread. When I have time I'll move it to my own small console app and give it a go there. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Neil there's nothing wrong with the TPL dataflow. Post your *test code*. xUnit or console, if you don't await for completion, you *will* get an abort exception when the application or test completes. If xUnit doesn't support async tests, call `Completion.Wait()` on the final block.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with TPL dataflow I just wanted to test another scenario. Will update the code as soon as I can

Comment: Could You please explain the context of 'this' in `await this.IndexLogEntriesAsync(le);` ?